# Unable to connect to Zeppelin server due to "Failed to load XML configuration"

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I've tried to connect hadoop, spark, and Zeppelin in Ubuntu 22.04, and I confirmed that hadoop and spark server is working well. But I can't connect to Zeppelin server. This is a log of zeppelin:

```
WARN \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,397\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[\<init\>\]:85) - Failed to load XML configuration, proceeding with a default,for a stacktrace activate the debug log
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,421\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[create\]:135) - Server Host: 127.0.0.1
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,421\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[create\]:139) - Server Port: 8080
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,421\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[create\]:141) - Context Path: /
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,424\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[create\]:142) - Zeppelin Version: 0.10.1
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,448\] ({main} Log.java\[initialized\]:169) - Logging initialized @1905ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
WARN \[2023-03-20 17:43:32,997\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[getConfigFSDir\]:653) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir
WARN \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,005\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[getConfigFSDir\]:653) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir
WARN \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,005\] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java\[getConfigFSDir\]:653) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir
WARN \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,067\] ({main} LocalConfigStorage.java\[loadCredentials\]:88) - Credential file /home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/conf/credentials.json is not existed
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,218\] ({ImmediateThread-1679301812982} PluginManager.java\[loadNotebookRepo\]:78) - Loading NotebookRepo Plugin: org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,534\] ({ImmediateThread-1679301812982} VFSNotebookRepo.java\[setNotebookDirectory\]:69) - Using notebookDir: /home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/notebook
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,718\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[setupWebAppContext\]:577) - warPath is: /home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/zeppelin-web-0.10.1.war
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,719\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[setupWebAppContext\]:590) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: /home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/webapps
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,802\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[setupWebAppContext\]:577) - warPath is: /home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,803\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[setupWebAppContext\]:590) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: /home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/webapps/next
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,820\] ({ImmediateThread-1679301812982} GitNotebookRepo.java\[init\]:76) - Opening a git repo at '/home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/notebook'
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,911\] ({main} NotebookServer.java\[\<init\>\]:154) - NotebookServer instantiated: org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@1500b2f3

INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,911\] ({main} NotebookServer.java\[setNotebook\]:165) - Injected NotebookProvider
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,911\] ({main} NotebookServer.java\[setServiceLocator\]:159) - Injected ServiceLocator: ServiceLocatorImpl(shared-locator,0,787738361)
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,912\] ({main} NotebookServer.java\[setNotebookService\]:172) - Injected NotebookServiceProvider
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,912\] ({main} NotebookServer.java\[setAuthorizationServiceProvider\]:179) - Injected NotebookAuthorizationServiceProvider
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,912\] ({main} NotebookServer.java\[setConnectionManagerProvider\]:185) - Injected ConnectionManagerProvider
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,914\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[setupClusterManagerServer\]:467) - Cluster mode is disabled
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,914\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[main\]:251) - Starting zeppelin server
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:33,917\] ({main} Server.java\[doStart\]:360) - jetty-9.4.31.v20200723; built: 2020-07-23T17:57:36.812Z; git: 450ba27947e13e66baa8cd1ce7e85a4461cacc1d; jvm 1.8.0_362-8u362-ga-0ubuntu1\~22.04-b09
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,063\] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java\[visitServlet\]:276) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,075\] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java\[doStart\]:334) - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,075\] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java\[doStart\]:339) - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,076\] ({main} HouseKeeper.java\[startScavenging\]:140) - node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,089\] ({main} ContextHandler.java\[log\]:2303) - Initializing Shiro environment
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,089\] ({main} EnvironmentLoader.java\[initEnvironment\]:133) - Starting Shiro environment initialization.
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:34,422\] ({main} EnvironmentLoader.java\[initEnvironment\]:147) - Shiro environment initialized in 333 ms.
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:37,854\] ({main} ContextHandler.java\[doStart\]:860) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@563f38c4{zeppelin-web,/,jar:file:///home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/zeppelin-web-0.10.1.war!/,AVAILABLE}{/home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/zeppelin-web-0.10.1.war}
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:37,897\] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java\[visitServlet\]:276) - NO JSP Support for /next, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:37,902\] ({main} ContextHandler.java\[log\]:2303) - Initializing Shiro environment
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:37,902\] ({main} EnvironmentLoader.java\[initEnvironment\]:133) - Starting Shiro environment initialization.

INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:37,921\] ({main} EnvironmentLoader.java\[initEnvironment\]:147) - Shiro environment initialized in 19 ms.
INFO \[2023-03-20 17:43:38,604\] ({main} ContextHandler.java\[doStart\]:860) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@53045c6c{zeppelin-web-angular,/next,jar:file:///home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war!/,AVAILABLE}{/home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin/zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war}
ERROR \[2023-03-20 17:43:38,633\] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java\[main\]:262) - Error while running jettyServer
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /127.0.0.1:8080
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:253)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:345)
... 7 more
```

---

And this is the code I changed in zeppelin-site.xml.template(in default, it didn't have zeppelin-site.xml)

```
<property>
    <name>zeppelin.server.addr</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    <description>Server binding address</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>zeppelin.server.port</name>
    <value>9999</value>
    <description>Server port.</description>
</property>
```

---

And this is the code I inserted in zeppelin-env.sh.template(also, no zeppelin-env.sh)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64  
export MASTER=spark://localhost:7077  
export ZEPPELIN_MEM="-Xms1g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g"  
export ZEPPELIN_INTP_MEM="-Xms1g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g"  
export SPARK_HOME=/home/nahyeon/apps/spark  
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/nahyeon/hdoop/hadoop-3.3.4/etc/hadoop  
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3  
export PYTHONPATH=python3  
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=9999
```

---

**paths of ~/.bashrc are:

```
export ZEPPELIN_HOME=/home/nahyeon/apps/zeppelin

export PATH=$PATH:$ZEPPELIN_HOME/bin
```

It seems like although I chose the port number which is different from spark's default port number(8080), it doesn't apply. And maybe it's because it couldn't find XML configuration, according to the first line of the log above. But I'm not sure I understood well, and I have no idea how to fix it. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Your 9999 value isn't being used. Something is running on port 8080 (Spark master runs on 7077, not 8080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I changed in zeppelin-site.xml.template(in default, it didn't have zeppelin-site.xml)

The template files need to be renamed for any property changes to take affect